# Equivalent of ActiveX("word.application") using XMLHttpRequest Javascript

Tags: javascript

We have a application which runs only in IE browser. I want it to be compatible with Firefox, chrome and other browser. Application uses ActiveX objects which doesn't support other browsers. I tried converting ActiveX to `XMLhttpRequest` but i do not know how to create office applications such as word, excel using `XMLhttpRequest`. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Code is as below.

```
var w= new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");

w.Visible = true;

obj= w.documents.open(doc)
```

What is the `XMLHttpRequest` equivalent code for above ?

Comment: firefox directly [state](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Protect-your-privacy/ActiveX/ta-p/1853) they won't support activex

Comment: Yes, thats the reason i am using XMLHttpRequest. What i want to know is how do i create / open word application using XMLHttprequest ?

Comment: you can't, no browser other then IE support activex. Even Edge will not!!! Perhaps you should look for an alternative solution, webdav maybe?

Comment: I am not using ActiveX for other browsers. I am using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` will never run a program on your machine, it's not designed for that. it's a replacement for `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` which works only in Internet explorer

Comment: It runs if CORS (Cross Origin resource Sharing) Add-on is installed in firefox.

Comment: @Ambika — No, it doesn't. XMLHttpRequest will never cause the browser to run an executable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent.

ActiveX is a Microsoft technology for loading libraries from other applications.

XMLHttpRequest is a standard technology for making HTTP requests.

The only connection between ActiveX and XMLHttpRequest is that the first implementation of XMLHttpRequest was done as an ActiveX control.

You can't use an HTTP request to create a Microsoft Office document.

Comment: Any other solution for this to work in firefox or any other browser other than IE ?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a standard tecnology from 2006, the activex implementation from microsoft was developed in 1999 from a concept interface developed the same year for "outlook web access" to exchange 2000. said that you deserve an upvote!